# TextBlock with hidden visibility isn't reserving space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm working on a punch clock application as a way of learning C#, XAML, and databases.  Right now, my GUI isn't behaving how I would like it to.

I have a `TextBlock` for each of my buttons like what is shown after Start Shift.  [image: gui after shift started]

However, when the dates are not valid, the `TextBlocks` are hidden.  I've been able to show and hide the visibility of these how I want to.  But, when I skip Start Lunch and End Lunch and go straight to End Shift, the End Shift `TextBlock` shows up after the Start Lunch Button as if the Start Lunch and End Lunch `TextBlocks` don't exist.
[image: gui after shift ended]

I've looked online and found that the visibility trait reserves space when it is hidden and doesn't reserve space when it is collapsed, but I am using hidden and it still isn't reserving space.  My code is shown below.

HomeView.xaml

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!--Left column buttons-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="10">
                <Button Width="140" Content="Start Shift" Command="{Binding startShiftCommand}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding startShiftActive}"/>
                <Button Width="140" Content="Start Lunch" Command="{Binding startLunchCommand}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding startLunchActive}"/>
                <Button Width="140" Content="End Lunch"   Command="{Binding endLunchCommand}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding endLunchActive}"/>
                <Button Width="140" Content="End Shift"   Command="{Binding endShiftCommand}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding endShiftActive}"/>
                <Button Width="140" Content="Add Break"   Command="{Binding addBreakCommand}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding addBreakActive}"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <!--Right column text blocks-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding day.timeIn,     StringFormat=t, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=StartTime}" FontSize="20"
                           Visibility="{Binding timeInValid,     Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
                           Padding="5" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding day.lunchStart, StringFormat=t, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=LunchStart}" FontSize="20"
                           Visibility="{Binding lunchStartValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
                           Padding="5" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding day.lunchEnd,   StringFormat=t, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="20"
                           Visibility="{Binding lunchEndValid,   Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           Padding="5" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding day.timeOut,    StringFormat=t, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=EndTime}" FontSize="20"
                           Visibility="{Binding timeOutValid,    Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           Padding="5" Margin="10"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

BooleanToVisibilityConverter.cs

```
public class BooleanToVisiblityConverter : BaseValueConverter<BooleanToVisiblityConverter>
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
            return (bool)value ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel.cs

```
    private void startShift()
    {
        day.date = DateTime.Now;
        dateValid = true;

        day.timeIn = DateTime.Now;
        timeInValid = true;

        day.breaks = new ObservableCollection<Break>();
        RaisePropertyChanged("day");    //A simple fix to update the UI

        process(Command.startShift);

        infoText = string.Format("Shift started at {0:t}", day.timeIn);

        writeToFile();
    }

    private void startLunch()
    {
        day.lunchStart = DateTime.Now;
        lunchStartValid = true;
        RaisePropertyChanged("day");

        process(Command.startLunch);

        infoText = string.Format("Lunch started at {0:t}", day.lunchStart);

        writeToFile();
    }

    private void endLunch()
    {
        day.lunchEnd= DateTime.Now;
        lunchEndValid = true;
        RaisePropertyChanged("day");

        process(Command.endLunch);

        infoText = string.Format("Lunch ended at {0:t}", day.lunchEnd);

        writeToFile();
    }

    private void endShift()
    {
        day.timeOut = DateTime.Now;
        timeOutValid = true;
        RaisePropertyChanged("day");

        calcTotalTime();

        process(Command.endShift);

        infoText = string.Format("Shift ended at {0:t}\nTotal time for {1:d} is {2}", day.timeOut, day.date, day.totalTime);

        //Save to database
        WorkHoursDBContext context = new WorkHoursDBContext();
        context.Days.Add(day);
        context.SaveChanges();

        writeToFile();
    }
```

The method `process()` is responsible for changing the `boolean` of each button to decide if it is enabled or not.

Is there any way I can prevent my End Shift `TextBlock` from sliding up when the Start Lunch and End Lunch `TextBlocks` are hidden?

Comment: Your issue is just simply a matter of layout rendering. When you're hiding your `TextBlock` it's still there and reserving the space of the control except without a populated string and your font size of that string, it's just a thin line. You could either set a fixed `Height` on your `TextBlock` instances, or the better method would be to use your `Grid` for what it's meant for and give each control its own cell instead of placing a separate `StackPanel` in two columns. If you'd like I can provide an example.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  I'll give those suggestions a try.  Thank you.

Comment: I got it to work with your suggestion to only use a 'grid' layout with rows and columns.  But, I still tried giving the 'TextBlocks' a fixed height within my 'StackPanel' and that didn't change anything.  The 'GUI' still shifted the End Shift text next to the Start Lunch 'Button'.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of StackPanel as they don't manage their space correctly. I try to avoid it as much as I can, designing my views with grids.

Comment: @Turk hmmm interesting, `Hidden` should reserve space as it's provided by the controls attributes, but a proper `Grid` is usually the better choice in scenarios like this for reasons like @JuanCarlosRodriguez pointed out.

Comment: @Turk That's why I said that. First of all, I kinda hate StackPanels, they f***d me so many times in cases like this one. A grid with 7 rows ( 4 for textblocks and 3 for the separators or empty rows with a fixed height ) and you are done. 0 spaces issues